# parsing json gives parseerror via getJSON

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

trying to implement some jquery.gantt and it needs some data. So manual says json data.(http://taitems.github.io/jQuery.Gantt/)

Created jquery:

```
    $(".gantt").gantt({
        source: basePath + "system/print_gantt_project_data.php?project_id=" + projectID,
        navigate: "scroll",
        scale: "weeks",
        maxScale: "months",
        minScale: "days",
        itemsPerPage: 10,
        onItemClick: function(data) {
            alert("Item clicked - show some details");
        },
        onAddClick: function(dt, rowId) {
            alert("Empty space clicked - add an item!");
        },
        onRender: function() {
         console.log("chart rendered");
        }
    });
```

and a script that could deliver the json data:

```
$aryOutput = array();
if($project_tasks) {
    foreach($project_tasks as $aryTask) {
        $aryOutput[] =  array(
            'name' => $aryTask['pt_name'],
            'desc' => $aryTask['pt_name'],
            'values' => array(array(
            'to' => '/Date('.strtotime($aryTask['pt_end_date']).')/',
            'from' => '/Date('.strtotime($aryTask['pt_start_date']).')/',
            'desc' => $aryTask['pt_description'],
            'label' => $aryTask['pt_description']
        ))
        );
    }
}
$strJSON = json_encode($aryOutput);
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo $strJSON;
```

On looking into the json delivered:

```
    [{"name":"test3","desc":"test3","values":[{"to":"\/Date(1442268000)\/","from":"\/Date(1442181600)\/","desc":"test3","label":"test3"}]},{"name":"test1","desc":"test1","values":[{"to":"\/Date(1442268000)\/","from":"\/Date(1442095200)\/","desc":"test1","label":"test1"}]},{"name":"test2","desc":"test2","values":[{"to":"\/Date(1442268000)\/","from":"\/Date(1442268000)\/","desc":"test2","label":"test2"}]}]
```

Taken from console.log in chrome. 
(based on the code inserted into jquery.fn.gantt.js:

```
            // **Create the chart**
            create: function (element) {

                // Initialize data with a json object or fetch via an xhr
                // request depending on `settings.source`
                if (typeof settings.source !== "string") {
                    element.data = settings.source;
                    core.init(element);
                } else {
                    $.getJSON(settings.source, function (jsData) {
                        element.data = jsData;
                        core.init(element);

                    })
  .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log('getJSON request failed! ' + textStatus); })
                }
            },
```

)

"getJSON request failed! parsererror"

Question is.. json seems legit - but the parseerror seems to contradict that.

Any one?

Comment: any extra characters being printed outside of the json in the response body of request?

Comment: Nope. Not even a UTF8-BOM

Answer (score 0):

Aaaand so I was wrong. Looking at the console in (shift+ctrl+i) chrome I found the culprit. It is an UTF8-BOM. So converting my script file to ASCII/DOS it all fell into place.

Wonder why everybody says that UTF8 is the "shit" ;)